# .NET Outlook Add-in: attaching a sent email item to a journal entry

Tags: .net, vb.net, outlook-addin

So I'm developing an outlook add-in that basically gathers some info from the user in the form, then sends a properly formatted email to the right person. What I want to do is then make a journal entry noting that the email had been sent, and attach the email in reference.

To accomplish this manually, I can go to the "Sent Items" folder, and simply drag the email of choice down over the Journal icon in the bottom-left menu, and this accomplishes what I'm trying to do programmatically.

Here is the code I'm using once the mail is sent:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend
    Cancel = False
    Dim sent As Outlook.MailItem = CType(Item, Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim app As New Outlook.Application

    Dim journal As Outlook.JournalItem = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olJournalItem)
    journal.Subject = sent.Subject & " - " & df.TextBox1.Text
    journal.Type = "E-mail Message"
    journal.Start = Now()
    journal.Duration = 0
    journal.Body = "Request sent to " & df.ComboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString()


    Try
        journal.Attachments.Add(sent, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByReference)
        journal.Save()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    df.Close()
End Sub
```

Its getting hung up at Attachments.Add and my error message is "an object could not be found". I'm guessing it means 'sent' is no good. However, I use sent.Subject to title the journal entry, and I do not get an error there. Any thoughts?

Your help is greatly valued!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your error is caused by Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByReference . Unfortunately I could not find, on google, any direct connection regarding OlAttachmentType and "an object could not be found" - so you either do the digging yourself or you provide more info.

Comment: Believe me, I've been digging for days.

Comment: so is it caused by Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByReference or not?

Comment: Yes, I have found out that it is. So, by using Type.Missing for that param, I've been able to embed it, however, double-clicking it in the journal entry gives me a blank email as if it were created new. Any thoughts?

Comment: Apparently the email doesnt get sent until that event is complete, which is why I can't reference it. Is there an event to handle once an email has been sent?

Comment: I am no Outlook interop expert :) - but:
- I don't think you can reference the email until it was sent -> you could use Type:=Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem to embed a copy of the message
- after the email was sent you should be able to reference it (by getting the email from the Sent folder) -